# SQL Server: Create New Records from Enumerated Date

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in the following general format:

```
id,transaction_dt,units,measures
1,2018-01-01,4,30.5
1,2018-01-03,4,26.3
2,2018-01-01,3,12.7
2,2018-01-03,3,8.8
```

What I am trying to accomplish is stack and enumerate the 'transaction_dt' based on the value of 'units' field in same record and unroll them into new records to produce something like this:

```
id,transaction_dt,measures
1,2018-01-01,30.5
1,2018-01-02,30.5
1,2018-01-03,30.5
1,2018-01-04,30.5
1,2018-01-03,26.3
1,2018-01-04,26.3
1,2018-01-05,26.3
1,2018-01-06,26.3
2,2018-01-01,12.7
2,2018-01-02,12.7
2,2018-01-03,12.7
2,2018-01-03,8.8
2,2018-01-04,8.8
2,2018-01-05,8.8
```

I currently have a python script that accomplishes this, but I think I might ultimately be best to do this server side for performance reasons.  Any advice on a performant SQL-based approach would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: You can try to use [WHILE LOOP](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/loops/while.php) then insert the result to one temp table.

Comment: @Sphinx a while loop is not a good way to handle this at all. We want to avoid looping whenever possible. A tally table is a much better approach. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far the easiest approach here is to use a numbers or tally table. I keep this as a view in my system like this. You can read a great article by Jeff Moden on the topic here. (You may notice my view is basically his doing, that he also borrowed). http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

```
create View [dbo].[cteTally] as

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N from cteTally
GO
```

Of course I don't have any sample data so first I have to make that.

```
declare @Something table
(
    id int
    , transaction_dt date
    , units int
    , measures decimal(7,2)
)
insert @Something
values

(1, '2018-01-01', 4, 30.5)
,(1, '2018-01-03', 4, 26.3)
,(2, '2018-01-01', 3, 12.7)
,(2, '2018-01-03', 3, 8.8)
```

Then to get the data the way you want is pretty simple.

```
select s.id
    , DATEADD(day, t.N - 1, s.transaction_dt)
    , s.measures
from @Something s
join cteTally t on t.N <= s.units
order by s.id
    , s.transaction_dt
    , t.N
```

Comment: Great solution. But it seems only work on SQL Server 2008 or over.

Comment: @Sphinx? Why do you say that? It is using a cte which was introduced in sql server 2005. If you are still using sql 2000 you needed to upgrade years ago anyway. But you can use the same technique, just need to populate the tally table differently. Tally tables have been a better solution than looping for a LONG LONG time.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't describe well. The official document shows [Table value constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql) supports 2008+. But anyway, 'tally' table is better solution than LOOP, and it can be built with other methods intead of 'Table value Constructor'.

Comment: The table value constructor is to generate the sample data which the OP did not provide. I could have used a series of inserts just as easily but it makes no difference because it was to generate sample data. That is exactly why I broke my answer into 3 pieces. And the table valued constructor was available in 2005. The documentation no longer lists versions which are out of mainstream support. As such, no mention of 2005. :)

Comment: @Sean Lange Thank you so much for your detailed answer!  This is a really great set-based approach.  Much better than looping based approaches.

Comment: You are quite welcome. And hopefully you added a few new tricks to the bag. :)