# Python Pandas: Equivalent Functionality of a SQL Tally/Number Table

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, numpy

I have come across an interesting technique that I am trying to find a pandas analog to if possible to test:

[SQL Server: Create New Records from Enumerated Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48774458/sql-server-create-new-records-from-enumerated-date?noredirect=1#comment84550752_48774458)

```
select s.id
    , DATEADD(day, t.N - 1, s.transaction_dt)
    , s.measures
from @Something s
join cteTally t on t.N <= s.units
order by s.id
    , s.transaction_dt
    , t.N
```

This seems really intriguing as a set-based solution.  My question is whether it would be possible to replicate something like this in pandas? :

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it's possible. I took the SQL example you referenced:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, '2018-01-01', 4, 30.5],
                   [1, '2018-01-03', 4, 26.3],
                   [2, '2018-01-01', 3, 12.7],
                   [2, '2018-01-03', 3, 8.8]],
                  columns=['id', 'transaction_dt', 'units', 'measures'])

df_out = pd.DataFrame([df.iloc[idx] for idx in df.index \
                       for _ in range(df.iloc[idx]['units'])])

#    id transaction_dt  units  measures
# 0   1     2018-01-01      4      30.5
# 0   1     2018-01-01      4      30.5
# 0   1     2018-01-01      4      30.5
# 0   1     2018-01-01      4      30.5
# 1   1     2018-01-03      4      26.3
# 1   1     2018-01-03      4      26.3
# 1   1     2018-01-03      4      26.3
# 1   1     2018-01-03      4      26.3
# 2   2     2018-01-01      3      12.7
# 2   2     2018-01-01      3      12.7
# 2   2     2018-01-01      3      12.7
# 3   2     2018-01-03      3       8.8
# 3   2     2018-01-03      3       8.8
# 3   2     2018-01-03      3       8.8
```